# Ubuntu 20.04 iMac 5k 2019 no sound

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on an iMac 5k 2019 and cannot get the sound to play from the inbuilt speakers.

Some info:

Soundcard is an Intel Cannon Lake, outout from `lspci -knn | grep Audio`

```
Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] [1002:aaf0]
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] [1002:aaf0]
```

The second card is the AMD HDMI one and works fine when connected.

I have played around and tried reinstalling PulseAudo and Alsamixer following instructions [like these](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/).

I have updated the kernel to the latest mainline version from Canonical which at the time of writing is 5.9 in the hope that newer drivers would fix the issue but no luck.

This seems like a common problem, does anyone out there have any more information and hopefully a fix for this?

Comment: Check the last post from this thread:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-sound-on-imac-5k-imac-19-1-27-2019/111631/15